# Creating an IIS 6.0 Application Pool using Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis-6

How do I create an Application Pool on IIS 6.0 using a PowerShell script?

This is what I have come up with so far ...

```
$appPool = [wmiclass] "root\MicrosoftIISv2:IIsApplicationPool"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't the most obvious process, but here is what worked for me..

```
$AppPoolSettings = [wmiclass]'root\MicrosoftIISv2:IISApplicationPoolSetting'
$NewPool = $AppPoolSettings.CreateInstance()
$NewPool.Name = 'W3SVC/AppPools/MyAppPool'
$Result = $NewPool.Put()
```

You might get an error with the call to Put(), but calling it a second (or third) time should make it work.  This is due to an issue with PowerShell V1 and WMI.

Comment: Thank you, works very well. I think I tried that, but was put off by that put error.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  That error is kind of distracting, but this is only V1 of PowerShell.

Answer (score 7):

Thought I might share the script I came up with. Thanks to goes to Steven and leon.

```
# Settings
$newApplication = "MaxSys.Services"
$poolUserName = "BRISBANE\svcMaxSysTest"
$poolPassword = "ThisisforT3sting"

$newVDirName = "W3SVC/1/ROOT/" + $newApplication
$newVDirPath = "C:\" + $newApplication
$newPoolName = $newApplication + "Pool"

#Switch the Website to .NET 2.0
C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis.exe -sn W3SVC/

# Create Application Pool
$appPoolSettings = [wmiclass] "root\MicrosoftIISv2:IISApplicationPoolSetting"
$newPool = $appPoolSettings.CreateInstance()
$newPool.Name = "W3SVC/AppPools/" + $newPoolName
$newPool.PeriodicRestartTime = 0
$newPool.IdleTimeout = 0
$newPool.MaxProcesses = 2
$newPool.WAMUsername = $poolUserName
$newPool.WAMUserPass = $poolPassword
$newPool.AppPoolIdentityType = 3
$newPool.Put()
# Do it again if it fails as there is a bug with Powershell/WMI
if (!$?) 
{
    $newPool.Put() 
}

# Create the virtual directory
mkdir $newVDirPath

$virtualDirSettings = [wmiclass] "root\MicrosoftIISv2:IIsWebVirtualDirSetting"
$newVDir = $virtualDirSettings.CreateInstance()
$newVDir.Name = $newVDirName
$newVDir.Path = $newVDirPath
$newVDir.EnableDefaultDoc = $False
$newVDir.Put()
# Do it a few times if it fails as there is a bug with Powershell/WMI
if (!$?) 
{
    $newVDir.Put() 
}

# Create the application on the virtual directory
$vdir = Get-WmiObject -namespace "root\MicrosoftIISv2" -class "IISWebVirtualDir" -filter "Name = '$newVDirName'"
$vdir.AppCreate3(2, $newPoolName)

# Updated the Friendly Name of the application
$newVDir.AppFriendlyName = $newApplication
$newVDir.Put()
```

Comment: @robert wagner - I would change your error handling to DO
{ $newVDir.Put()} WHILE (!$?)  Then you will not need to have the first Put().  The do/while loop will keep performing the put until there is no error.  Just a suggestion.

Comment: It might get stuck in an infinite loop, but it's a thought.

Comment: you could always have a little counter, an only retry up to a maximum number of times.

Answer (score 0):

All is well! I modified the code so there is an explicit call to the $newPool.Put() command after the initial error. Thanks for your help!