# When creating App Pool and Virtual Dir Config

Tags: powershell, iis-6

I'm using the app pool and virtual directory created [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261237/creating-an-iis-6-0-application-pool-using-powershell)
and I'm trying to figure out how to set the recycle worker processes in minutes for the app pool and for the virtual directory I'm trying to change the execute permissions to scripts and executables, adding the same username and password permissions for the virtual directory and not sure if this is possible but add a mapping all in powershell.  Also I'm using iis 6.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright here are the added information:

```
$newPool.PeriodicRestartTime = 60  #sets the recycle worker processes(in minutes)

$newVDir.AccessExecute = $True               #sets execuatable access
$newVDir.AccessScript = $True                #sets script access
$newVDir.AnonymousUserName = $poolUserName   #sets user name
$newVDir.AnonymousUserPass = $poolPassword   #sets user password
```

I still haven't found out how to add additional mappings but see'ing if Microsoft can answer some of it's questions.

Good luck.